# Cannot substring from half to last letter

Tags: c#, string, substring

So I'm trying to do some experiments with SteamKit2.
And when I've been trying to make a command-like switch for switching games, a problem appeared. The command it self is '!play *STEAM GAME APPID*'. What I wanted the substring to do, is only retrieve the AppID number - without the '!play ' part.  I SubStringed it from 6 (since empty spaces are counted as characters aswell), but now I am unsure on how to make it so it substrings from 6 to the max. What I used is in below, but It doesn't work (Throws me System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException).

```
private const string PlayCmd = "!play";
ProcessCommandSystem("!play 440");

private void ProcessCommandSystem(string message)
{
    if (message.StartsWith(PlayCmd))
    {
        int appidnumeral;
        string appidraw = message.Substring(6, (message.Length));
        int.TryParse(appidraw, out appidnumeral);
        Bot.SetGamePlaying(appidnumeral);
    }
}
```

Not sure why doesn't this work, but what I'm trying to do later on In the code, is to convert the string into an Integer value, since SetGamePlaying doesn't seem to accept strings, that's why I want to substring it (to cut the '!Play' off, so only numbers) and to convert the substringed thing later on to an Integer value, for use for SetGamePlaying.

Comment: string appidraw = message.Replace("!play ", "")

Comment: @OguzOzgul, this probably work in this scenario, but not in general: it will remove every occurrence of "!play " within the string, not just the starting one

Comment: Do you think I don't know that :) He is trying to get the rest of the string starting from the end of "!play ". This is safer at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to take the full length of the string:

```
string appidraw = message.Substring(6, (message.Length));
```

which is out of range of the input string.

You need to shorten the amount you take by the start position:

```
string appidraw = message.Substring(6, (message.Length - 6));
```

so that the length remains in range. However, as Tim points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33960010/59303), you don't need the length argument at all if you are simply taking the right hand part of the string:

```
string appidraw = message.Substring(6);
```

Alternatively you simply remove the command from the string:

```
string appidraw = message.Replace("!play ", "");
```

however, this will remove **all** occurrences of "!play" not just the first, so it should be used with care.

Answer (score 2):

Substring expects the length as second parameter, the length from the start index. If you add `message.Length` to 6 you clearly exceed the string's length by 6.

If you want to take the rest use the [overload without a second parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string appidraw = message.Substring(6);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Substring` takes two arguments: the starting index, and the length of the substring. Your first argument is correct, but you'll need to change your second argument to `(message.Length) - 6` to give:

```
string appidraw = message.Substring(6, (message.Length - 6));
```

As a sidenote, in C#, you count from `0` instead of `1`, so the index of the last character in the string will be its length less `1`. Therefore, if you need to refer to the last character, you can use `message.Length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`Substring` wants starting index and number of char to pick up, not last index (which anyway would be `message.Length -1)`

use

```
string appidraw = message.Substring(6, (message.Length - 6));
```